# kill a remote linux process from c#

Tags: c#, .net, linux, kill-process

i want to know ways by which i can kill a remote linux process by name from c# 
i tried using pskill but it is not working ....can any one please help me with this

```
string processName = "/bin/bash";
                    ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        Arguments = $" -t  {RemoteMachineName} -u {username} -p {password} {processName}", // also kill all the child processes
                        CreateNoWindow = false,
                        RedirectStandardError = false,
                        RedirectStandardInput = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PsKillExecutablePath"]
                    };

                    var p = Process.Start(pInfo);
                    // wait for the process to exit 
                    p.WaitForExit(1000 * 60); // Wait for 60 seconds
                    if (p.ExitCode != 0)
                    {
                        logger.Error("Unable to kill the process on the remote machine ... ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Info("Sucessfully Killed remote process ... ");
                    }
```

Comment: maybe simply use `killall` command ? processName =  `/usr/bin/killall`. you can find it's path easily `which killall`

Comment: @AdityaSingh so it's a Windows tool. Why do you expect it to do anything to *Linux* machines?

Comment: i am not getting output ....its just showing usage ... can pskill be used to kill a process on a remote linux machine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes is was suspecting that ... then how to kill a linux remote process from c# ... any suggestions

Comment: If you want something that works across platforms, you can use [Powershell Core Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7), assuming Powershell Core is installed on the remote machine. The common way to manage Linux is through SSH. There are few SSH libraries for .NET though. Most people use [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) which hasn't been updated for 2 years